# How to Replace Text Surrounding Text in Notepad++'s Regular Expression Finder Dialog?

Tags: php, regex, notepad++

This question is the opposite from other regex notepad++ questions.
Instead of changing text between text, I need to replace text that is surrounding, like that:

*from*

$_REQUEST['**action**']

*to*

getReq('**action**')

*So:*

I wish to replace `$_REQUEST(` for `getReq(` and at same time replace `]` for `)`.

How can I achieve that in Notepad++ ? There are more than a 1000 hits and I want to replace it all, not just the ones with **action** index, but many more!

Comment: How does it connected with programming?

Comment: The "help center" link for *Off Topic* specifically includes "software tools commonly used by programmers;". Notepad++ is one such.

Comment: Can you give us a better sense of what your _general_ replacement is?

Comment: Err.. the link for [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says the same... "if your question generally covers ... software tools commonly used by programmers ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still want to match, you just want match with capture (Notepad supports this, make sure Regex is checked in search and replace. The ( ) is the capture group, the order of the first ( is the capture group number. (?: ) can be used to make a group non-capture)

Match on `\$_REQUEST\['([^']*)'\]`

Replace using capture with `getReq\('$1'\)`

EDIT: In Notepad, you have to escape () for some reason in the replace part

Comment: probably need some escape characters in there: `\$_REQUEST\['([^']+)'\]` > `getReq\('$1'\)` NP++ may treat both the pattern and the replacement as RegExps.

Comment: @CD001 right, Thanks. You can't regex the replace part though. It basically just recognizes $#.

Comment: In theory yes - but NP++ just stripped the parentheses from my replacement when I didn't escape them \*shrugs\*

Comment: I tested it and then the result was `getReq'mail'` how can I correct that? Oh my god!

Comment: ^ first Ctrl + Z to undo ;) next escape the parentheses in the replacement so `getReq\('$1'\)` ... same thing happened to me. @EASI

Comment: There is not Ctrl+Z in Replace in Files... I think... 8-[

Comment: @EASI As long as you don't close the file, You should be able to use undo on it. up till the point of when you first opened it.

Comment: erk - in which case you'll probably need to match on `getReq'([^']+)'` and replace with `getReq\('$1'\)` that should replace your replacements ... but test it in one file first! :) @EASI

Comment: @Tezra - I think he's used the *Find in files* option in NP++ which doesn't open the files, merely runs the RegExp over all the files (of the specified type) in a given directory...

Comment: @EASI Before hitting "REPLACE ALL", I recommend hitting replace next a couple times until you are satisfied that it is doing what you want.

Comment: You shouldn't have saved the file(s). @EASI

Comment: Thank you all! Worked well.

Comment: @revo - it's automatic when you use the *Replace in files* option in NP++ it's like doing a `grep`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a *capturing group* in your regex. In most regex engines, capturing groups are indicated with parentheses, possibly escaped with backslashes in front:

```
foo(capturing_group)bar

foo\(capturing group\)bar
```

Notepad++ uses PCRE, I think, so it should be bare parens (the first example, above).

What you have is a larger pattern:

```
$_REQUEST['some variable text goes here']
```

You want to replace that with

```
getReq('some variable text goes here')
```

The capturing group will "capture" (or "save") the variable text, and a *backreference* to the group will "insert" the text in your replacement:

```
$_REQUEST['([^']*)']   

getReq('\1')
```

The search would be for the outside text, `$_REQUEST['` and `']`, plus a capturing group `(` ... `)` containing `[^']*` any number of characters that are not single quotes.

The replacement would be the outside replacement text, `getReq('` and `')`, plus a backreference to the first (and only!) capturing group in the original match. The `\1` is replaced by everything matched inside the first set of parens.

FYI: Groups are generally numbered by counting opening parentheses. So a nested group like this: `( ( ) ) ( ( ) )` would be numbered `(1 (2 ) ) (3 (4 ) )`.